# Read local xml file in app iOS

Tags: ios, xml, nsxmlparser, nsbundle

In the bundle I have a connection to an external folder that is blue color and not the usual yellow color. 
Inside this folder there is an xml file from which I have to read the content.

This is the xml file from which I derive the value of "id":

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <root>
    <event id="2"></event>
   </root>
```

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


   NSString *pathFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
   NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[pathFile stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"config.xml"]];
   NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
   NSXMLParser *parser = [[ NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
   NSLog(@"the parser xml is %@", parser);

   //the parser xml is <NSXMLParser: 0x967d870>

  [parser setDelegate:self];

  BOOL success = [parser parse];

    if(success == YES){

       NSLog(@"success");
    } else {

        NSLog(@" not success"); //is not success, why?
    }

 [parser release];
}


 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

   //in this method does not enter

   if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"event"]){

      NSLog(@" %@", elementName);

    }

}
```

Comment: If `[parser parse]` fails then you can print `[parser parserError]` to get some information about the failure.

Comment: I get like error: (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 5.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blue folders in Xcode appear as actual folders in your app's bundle. This means you need to include the folder name in the file's path in your code:

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *folderPath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"folderName"];
NSString *path = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"config.xml"];
```

Replace `folderName` with the actual name of your folder.

Or you can do:

```
NSURL *xmlURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"config" withExtension:@"xml" subdirectory:@"folderName"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
    NSString *configFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"XMLFileName"];

    NSDictionary *settingsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
    pathForResource:configFileURL ofType:@"xml"]];
```